# Send [InputBox] and [Listbox] Parameters on controller

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using both [InputBox/ListBox] for filtering, but I'm not sure where I was wrong. I tried reacthoooks but I'm new to reactjs and reacthooks, which are a bit difficult for me to understand for now (1st year college)

Here is my code..

**Model**

```
export class AddNewApplication {
    constructor() {
      this.search=undefined;
      this.applicationStatus=undefined;
    }
}
```

**Function**

```
  handleChangeSearch(event) {
    let addAppTemp = this.state.addApp;
    addAppTemp.search = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      addApp: addAppTemp 
    });
    this.RPTList(event.target.value, addAppTemp.status);
  }

  handleChangeStatus(event) {
    let addAppTemp = this.state.addApp;
    addAppTemp.status = event.target.value;
    this.setState({
      addApp: addAppTemp
    });
    this.RPTList(addAppTemp.search, event.target.value);
  }

  async RPTList(filter, status) {
    const respone = await fetch("/api/Application/api/filter="+Filter+"$Status="+Status);
    const data = await respone.json();
    this.setState({ rpt: data, loading: false });
  }
```

**ListBox Component**

```
<Input id="applicationStatus" type="select" onChange={handle} name="applicationStatus" value={value}>
   <option value="">Status</option>
   {appStatus.map(appStatus =>
      <option key={appStatus.id} value={appStatus.id}>{appStatus.name}</option>
   )}
</Input>
```

**[InputBox/ListBox]**

```
<Row className="px-2 pb-2">
   <Col sm="7" xs="7">
      <Input type="text" value={this.state.addApp.search} onChange={this.handleChangeSearch} style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}></Input>
  </Col>
   <Col sm="5" xs="5" className="text-right px-3">
      <ApplicationStatusSelect value={this.state.addApp.applicationStatus} handle={this.handleChangeStatus} appStatus={this.state.status}/>
   </Col>
</Row>
```

**Result will thrown here**

somewhere on my constructor
`addApp: new AddNewApplicatio`

```
<ApplicationList records={this.state.rpt}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my perspective, your RPT Function should look like this, and also answer your question.

read this React Training it might help you : https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/route-props

```
async RPTList(filter = undefined, status = undefined) {
  const sFilter = `${filter !== undefined? `filter=${filter}`:''}${filter !== undefined && status !== undefined? '&':''}${status !== undefined? `status=${status}`:''}`;
  const respone = await fetch(`/api/Application/api/ApplicationList${sFilter !== ''? `?${sFilter}`:''}`);
  const data = await respone.json();
  this.setState({ rpt: data, loading: false });
}
```

just comment if there's more problem, you didn't show your controller tho...